# Garbage collecting a Gen 1 object which is referenced by an unrooted Gen 2 object

Tags: .net, garbage-collection

I have found an interesting statement in [.NET Performance Testing and Optimization - The Complete Guide](http://www.red-gate.com/community/books/dotnet-performance-testing-complete-guide) book on page 228:

> It's worth noting that any Gen 1 object which is referenced by an unrooted Gen 2 object is not
> collected in a Gen 1 collection, but only in a Gen 2 collection, when its parent is collected.

Is it right, and if so, for what reasons?

Comment: If an object is referenced by another object that hasn't been collected yet, the child object itself won't be collected, the reason is obvious. If the parent is unrooted, you'd think that the child would be collected, but the problem is that the GC doesn't know that yet. If it knew or if it tried to find out, then it wouldn't be a Gen 1 collection, it'd be a Gen 2. And that's pretty much what it does, it waits for a Gen 2 to occur.

Comment: You right, but what about Gen 0 and Gen 1 in the same situation? authors of the book didn't accent on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine that it is because the Gen 1 object is rooted/referenced by the Gen 2 object, so the Gen 1 object can't be collected until it is no longer referenced, which will be when the Gen 2 object referencing it is collected.

Comment: but Gen 2 object isn't application's roots like global and static object or local variable/parameter object pointers on a thread's stack, isn't it ?